# how to know remotely if spark job is running on cluster

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce, spark-streaming, bigdata

I am running spark job on ec2 cluster, I have a trigger that submits job periodically. I do not want to submit job if one job is already running on cluster. Is there any api that can give me this information?

Answer (score 1):

Spark, and by extension, Spark Streaming offer an operational REST API at `http://<host>:4040/api/v1`

Consulting the status of the current application will give you the information sought.

Check the documentation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/monitoring.html#rest-api

Answer (score 0):

you can consult the UI to see the status
eg.
If you run locally, take a look at the localhost:4040